# Submanifold of a Hyperkahler manifold which is 'Lagrangian' w.r.t. all three symplectic structures

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hyperkaehler

Let $X$ be a hyperkaehler manifold. Being hyperkaehler, it has three distinguished Kaehler forms, $\omega^u$ ($u$=1,2,3), corresponding to its three distinguished almost complex structures.

How does one describe a submanifold, $S$, of $X$ which is 'Lagrangian' with respect to all three Kaehler forms, i.e., $$\omega^u(T_1,T_2)=0$$ where $T^1$ and $T^2$ are arbitrary tangent vectors of $S$, and
$$
\omega^u(N_1,N_2)=0
$$
where $N^1$ and $N^2$ are arbitrary normal vectors of $S$. Is it a middle-dimensional submanifold?

Comment: Not when the dimension is $4$.  All 1-dimensional submanifolds are multi-Lagrangian, but no $2$-dimensional submanifold is.  In general, the largest multi-Lagrangian submanifold in dimension $4n$ has dimension $n$.

Comment: @RobertBryant Your answer seems to me to contradict the answer by user25309 below, perhaps you could comment on this ?

Comment: @RobertBryant ... or write an alternative answer, hopefully with some references ?

Comment: The question is what you want to call a 'Lagrangian' submanifold in this context.  I was using it to mean a *maximal* submanifold $S$ with the property that all $3$ of the distinguished Kähler forms vanish when pulled back to $S$.  For this criterion, the maximum dimension of such an $S$ is $n$ (when $X$ has dimension $4n$).  Some people might want $S$ to have dimension $2n$, but, clearly, no $S$ of dimension $2n$ can be Lagrangian with respect to all $3$ of the distinguished Kähler forms.

Comment: @RobertBryant Does the restriction on the dimension of $S$ (i.e., being at most quarter-dimensional) hold when we relax the requirement of it being multi-Lagrangian to it just being multi-isotropic, i.e., only the first condition in the question above holds?

Comment: Yes, it does.  In fact, as my comment above was meant to communicate, 'multi-isotropic', in your terminology is the only condition that I was using.

Answer (score 2):

Such submanifold does not exist (in physics terminology, there are no 
$(A,A,A)$-branes). A submanifold which is Lagrangian with respect to two symplectic forms, say $\omega_2$ and $\omega_3$, is necessarily holomorphic with respect to the complex structure $I_1$, and in particular $\omega_1$ restricted to the submanifold is a Kähler form (and so not zero).

Comment: Robert Bryant seems to indicate in his comment that 'multi-Lagrangian' submanifolds exist, so perhaps you could provide a reference?

Comment: According to the usual definition, a Lagrangian submanifold is half-dimensional (and the definition given in the question: tangent bundle isotropic and normal bundle isotropic, is equivalent to the usual one).  My guess is that Robert Bryant means 'multi-isotropic' rather than 'multi-Lagrangian'.